# Listing File Names in Folder

Tags: c, visual-c++

I am trying to list filtered files in a directory.
If I use 3-character extension, the code works OK
If I use 4-character extension, the code craches

I am running the code under Visual Studio 2012

If i use

```
ListDirectoryContents(L"*.txt",   &x,   pList_Files);
```

it is OK.

If I use

```
ListDirectoryContents(L"*.txtx",  &x,   pList_Files);
```

code crashes.

```
bool ListDirectoryContents
(const wchar_t * sDir,  unsigned int * Num_files,  wchar_t ** FileList)
{    
    WIN32_FIND_DATA     fdFile; 
    HANDLE          hFind = NULL; 
    wchar_t         sPath[2048]; 
    unsigned            int k = 0;

    wsprintf(sPath, L"%s", sDir); 

    if((hFind = FindFirstFile(sPath, &fdFile)) == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
    { 
        wprintf(L"Path not found: [%s]\n", sDir); 
        return false; 
    } 

    do
    { 
         //Find first file will always return "."
         //    and ".." as the first two directories. 
        if(wcscmp(fdFile.cFileName, L".") != 0 && wcscmp(fdFile.cFileName, L"..") != 0) 
        { 
            //Build up our file path using the passed in 
            //  [sDir] and the file/foldername we just found: 
            //wsprintf(sPath, L"%s\\%s", sDir, fdFile.cFileName); 

            wsprintf(sPath, L"%s", fdFile.cFileName); 

            //Is the entity a File or Folder? 
            if(fdFile.dwFileAttributes &FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY) 
            { 
                //wprintf(L"Directory: %s\n", sPath); 

                ListDirectoryContents(sPath, Num_files, FileList); //Recursion, I love it! 
            } 
            else
            { 
                wsprintf(FileList[k], L"%s", fdFile.cFileName); 
                //wsprintf(FileList[k], L"%s", sPath); 
                k++;

                //wprintf(L"%s \n", sPath);  
           } 
        }
    } 
    while(FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile)); //Find the next file. 

    FindClose(hFind); //Always, Always, clean things up! 

    *Num_files = k;

    return true; 
}
```

Comment: Crash where? Use the debugger.

Comment: Also your recursion is wrong: you always index from 0 in the list overwriting the previous iteration. Perhaps there's more *.txtx files in your search and you exceed the bounds of the `FileList`? - do tell us where it crashes.